# Any idea how to decode these little endian bytes in python?

Tags: python, hex, bluetooth-lowenergy, unpack

I am picking up advertising data from a BLE device. In particular I am interested in these two bytes:

```
b'\x17d\x0e\x10\x0e\xd7\x02\x1d\x00G\x00U\x01\x00'
b'\x02\xad\x02\x8d\x00\x9b\x00\x0e\x01\xf6\x01\xad\x00\xcf\x00V\x01-\x01+\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

In the manual for the device, which is available [here](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/TemperatureHumidityDataLoggerCommandsAPI24.2837071165/html). They give a structure for the advertising data. I tried to follow that and use `struct.unpack` as shown below:

```
import struct

bte = b'\x17d\x0e\x10\x0e\xd7\x02\x1d\x00G\x00U\x01\x00'
struct.unpack('<BBHHHH', bte)
```

However, I get this error "unpack requires a buffer of 10 bytes". I think this has something to do with the first byte `\x17d\` as `struct.unpack` always returns this error when you have a byte with more than two characters. Also the bytes `\x00G\` and `\x00U\` as I am not sure what the U and G mean. Also this byte is 11 long while a byte of the format `<BBHHHH` should be only 10 long.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `BBHHHH` expects 10 bytes (1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2), but `b'\x17d\x0e\x10\x0e\xd7\x02\x1d\x00G\x00U\x01\x00'` appears to be 14 bytes. Your format string is off.

Comment: btw the first byte is `0x17` and the second byte is `0x64` otherwise known in the ascii world as: `d`.

Comment: Yes, I've fallen for that before. Note that only the two digits after `\x` are part of that literal. `\x00G` as another example is a null byte (`00`), and `"G"`; so two bytes in total.

Comment: Did you mean: `struct.unpack('<BBHHHH', bte[:10])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Blue Maestro devices I don't think they put the data in little endian format in the advertisement manufacturer data.

Looking at your data I would expect it to be something like the following:

```py
import binascii
from pprint import pprint
from struct import unpack

pckt = binascii.unhexlify('17640e100ed7021d004700550100')
data = {}

data["version"] = unpack(">B", pckt[0:1])[0]
data["batt_lvl"] = unpack(">B", pckt[1:2])[0]
data["interval"] = unpack(">H", pckt[2:4])[0]
data["log_count"] = unpack(">H", pckt[4:6])[0]
data["humidity"] = unpack(">h", pckt[6:8])[0] / 10
data["dew_point"] = unpack(">h", pckt[8:10])[0] / 10
data["temperature"] = unpack(">h", pckt[10:12])[0] / 10
pprint(data)
```

Giving an output of:

```py
{'batt_lvl': 100,
 'dew_point': 7.1,
 'humidity': 54.1,
 'interval': 3600,
 'log_count': 3799,
 'temperature': 8.5,
 'version': 23}
```

You can do the unpack in one go but you will have to adjust the values for dew point humidity, and temperature:

```
unpack('>BBHHhhh', pckt[:12])
# (23, 100, 3600, 3799, 541, 71, 85)
```

When picking out individual values it can be clearer to use the `int.from_bytes` functionality.

```py
import binascii
from pprint import pprint

pckt = binascii.unhexlify('17640e100ed7021d004700550100')
data = {}

data["version"] = int.from_bytes(pckt[0:1], byteorder='big')
data["batt_lvl"] = int.from_bytes(pckt[1:2], byteorder='big')
data["interval"] = int.from_bytes(pckt[2:4], byteorder='big')
data["log_count"] = int.from_bytes(pckt[4:6], byteorder='big')
data["humidity"] = int.from_bytes(pckt[6:8], byteorder='big', signed=True) / 10
data["dew_point"] = int.from_bytes(pckt[8:10], byteorder='big', signed=True) / 10
data["temperature"] = int.from_bytes(pckt[10:12], byteorder='big', signed=True) / 10
pprint(data)
```

Which gives the same values:

```py
{'batt_lvl': 100,
 'dew_point': 7.1,
 'humidity': 54.1,
 'interval': 3600,
 'log_count': 3799,
 'temperature': 8.5,
 'version': 23}
```

The `\x17d`, `\x00G`, and `\x00U` are all two bytes. However the second bytes happen to be ASCII values so Python, when displaying, helpfully displays the letter rather than the byte value.
To prove prove this we can input byte values and see ASCII value in the output:

```
>>> b'\x64\x47\x55'
b'dGU'
```

There are a few things you can do to show the actual byte value to help with debugging.

Use hexlify:

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(bte)
b'17640e100ed7021d004700550100'
```

Convert the bytes to a list of denary values:

```
>>> list(bte)
[23, 100, 14, 16, 14, 215, 2, 29, 0, 71, 0, 85, 1, 0]
```

Format it as a string with the hex values:

```
>>> [f'{n:02X}' for n in bte]
['17', '64', '0E', '10', '0E', 'D7', '02', '1D', '00', '47', '00', '55', '01', '00']
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked perfectly for me. Wasn't aware of the `int.from_bytes` method. Also as others have pointed out the `\x17d`, `\x00G`, and `\x00U` are all two bytes like you said which was confusing me. I did some debugging using the app on my phone which shows the temperature and I think you may have some of the values mislabeled but other than that this works perfectly!